# How to move a item from one recycler view to another

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I saw in `Vidma Recorder Lite` that the item moves from one recycler view to another.
[See the video](https://streamable.com/nae5vx). How can I achieve such a animation.

PS: I have the same model and the same view for both the recycler views.

Comment: Looks like default recycler view item inserted and item removed animations.

Comment: watch it in 0.5 x. Then you will see the difference